# How do I display information using MYSQLi and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using MYSQLi (from this website: http://codular.com/php-mysqli) and getting a blank page.

```
<html>
<body>  
    <h1>TEST21</h1>

    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'Brendan', 'password', 'Library');

    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

    echo "STEP1";

    //STEP 2

    $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM 'BOOK'
        WHERE 'ISBN10' > 0
    SQL;

    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }

    echo "STEP2";

    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Turn your [error reporting](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) all the way up on development servers.

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Awesome! I got some errors now:Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Library_Site/index.php:4) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Library_Site/index.php on line 7
LINE 7
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Library_Site/index.php on line 10

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_database() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Library_Site/index.php on line 11

Comment: After taking a moment to read the stupid things, I realized that I wasn't even using MYSQLi. I'll try to fix that, but in the meantime, the fatal error is what's worrying me. Anyone know anything about that?

Comment: It's mysql_select_db() not mysql_select_database().  That's the cause of the fatal error.  However, do go ahead and switch to the mysqli driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whacky thing with HEREDOC is that the closing identifier must not have any leading spaces (must not be indented). See the big warning here - http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

You're also using the wrong quote characters in your query. I'd simplify it all down to this...

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `BOOK` WHERE `ISBN10` > 0';
```

Comment: YES! THANK YOU! I've been working on that for hours!